# Can I share VirtualBox images between Windows and Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, multi-boot, ntfs-3g

I have an Ubuntu 18.10 and Windows 10 dualboot on my laptop and I'm using VirtualBox 5.2 and 6.0 on both host OS. My guests are usually Ubuntu systems. I share some data between the different OS by mounting the NTFS partition in Ubuntu (and mount-bind or link certain directories from it), e.g. the Maven Cache which works fine because Java archives are designed to be portable between OS.

Can I do the same for VirtualBox images, i.e. is there some evidence that the VirtualBox image format is written and read in the same way on all systems.

Could there be an issue with access through different VirtualBox major versions 5.x and 6.x? Within Ubuntu 18.10 there doesn't seem to be one, but that might change when accessing images from different OS.

Natuarally, only one system will access the image file at the same time on the dualboot setup.

Comment: The fileformat should be the same, so in theory what you want to do should be possible.

Comment: The virtualbox documentation should show how to move or copy "virtual disks" between hosts. That section might be relevant in this situation.